# PHP search using database records

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, search-engine

I'm trying to make a PHP search form that lets you search for something, then compares it to the record with the `Name` field that most closely matches it. Then, it would open the URL specified in the `src` field of the same record in the database. I've been looking around many websites but I can't find a tutorial for this, does anyone know a good one or know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Fuzzy searching? Database interaction? Redirection? I'm pretty sure there won't be a tutorial for *exactly* this package of functions, but there is a ton of stuff for each individual element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MySql **like** clause

```
"SELECT * FROM table where field like '%{$searchTerm}%'"
```

Now fetch the **src** field from the selected record.